# generate excel on the fly and send it on tornado-python server

Tags: python, excel, tornado, xls

I want to write some x records at a time in an excel file and as they are written, I want to send the data through tornado server so that my download process is similar to that of a browser download( downloading in parts, y.xls.part). 
Is there a way I can write and send data in chunks?

Thanks

Comment: A excel file can't be streamed in parts.

Comment: what if we convert it to xml excelsheet and then stream it?

Comment: Don't know what you mean with _**convert to XML excelsheet**_. The `xlsx` file have to be completed, saved and all `filehandle` closed. You can save to a in memory `io.BytesIO` object if you want to avoid using a `tempfile`.